# Redirecting nginx to another internal port not working

Tags: nginx, port-forwarding, jetty

I have an nginx instance running on port 80 and another app (embedded jetty) running on the same machine on port `4567`.

I'm trying to redirect any request that includes `/api/` in the URL, to the server running on port `4567`.

For this, I've added the following inside the http context tag in the `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
        }
}
```

But this is not working. I simply get a `404 Not Found` from nginx whenever I try to request any URL that includes `/api/`*.

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you location is incorrect, use

```
location /api/ { 
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567; 
}
```

Add slash in the end of your location.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Instead of adding this configuration to `nginx.conf`, I added it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` and it seems to have done the trick.

Comment: The best practice is to create a new file in `sites-available`, and make a symbolic link to `sites-enabled`. This way every virtualhost has its own configuration file. In your case, you could remove `sites-enabled/default`, to remove the current default vhost, and make a new one with another file.